# Spring OAuth2 along local authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth

I would like to add a second method of authentication (OAuth2) to my Spring boot application.

So far I have implemented local authentication (username + password stored in my own database) and it works perfectly.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1000)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public static BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    // Enable jdbc authentication
    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/")
                .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/welcome")
                .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/getEmployees")
                .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/addNewEmployee")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

For OAuth2, I figured out that I only need to ad **@EnableOAuth2Sso** and

```
 facebook.app.id=xxx
 facebook.app.secret=xxx
```

in my application proprieties.

It works ,but this overrides my local authentication (/login redirects to fb instead of the login.html page).

Is there a (simple) way to keep both auth strategies?

Thanks in advance!